# C# inheritance using generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, .net-core

```
public abstract class GenericClass<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public T Entity { get; set; }
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public abstract string Prop2 { get;  set; }
}

public class Child1 : GenericClass<Entity1>
{
    public override string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Child2 : GenericClass<Entity2>
{
    public override string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child1> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child2> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Entity3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Hello,
I have the above class structure. I have Entity1 and Entity2 which have one-to-many relationships with Child1 and Child2 respectively. Here EntityId represents the foreign key. Child1 and Child2 are inherited from the GenericClass.
I want to differentiate Entity1 and Entity2 from Entity3 as the first two have Children property while the third one doesn't. I am thinking about adding an Interface like "IEntityWithChildren"

```
public interface IEntityWithChildren<T>
//where: T is Child1 or Child2
{
    IEnumerable<T> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and inherit Entity1 and Entity2 from this interface like:

```
public class Entity1 : IEntityWithChildren<Child1>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child1> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I am not able to make it work, your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What you've described works just fine. Are you trying to load this object graph using an ORM?
You should remove the `EntityId` and `Prop1` properties from the derived types of `GenericClass`, they exist but are not overridable on `GenericClass`. This can lead to some unexpected behaviour when accessing these properties.

Comment: Thank you @PaulG, yes you are right, it was a mistake, I updated the code by removing the unnecessary properties. I want to check certain Entities if they are of type IEntityWithChildren<T> or not and then process them. I am not able to form the where clause for this interface.